# GDB logging file location

Tags: gdb

Hi I am new to GDB. I used the "set logging on" command. It creates a default file "gdb.txt" to store the output. However, I am unable to locate the file and see the data. Can you please tell me where the file is located?

Answer (score 6):

In the current working directory. Try `pwd` command at the `(gdb)` prompt.

Comment: For me, `pwd` gives the folder that I expect the "gdb.txt" file to be in, but there is no file. `show logging` states that it should be written to said file.

Answer (score 1):

the gdb.txt file will not be created in pwd always.
It has to be explicitly specified by executing command 'set logging on' in gdb terminal.